# Invoking by reflection a private static method

Tags: java, reflection

When I call java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke() method on a private static method, I get a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : wrong number of arguments". I think I respect javadoc specification, did I something wrong ? Thanks for any help.

Here is my code :

```
public class MyClass {
    ....
    private static Object myMethod(String[] stringArray) {...}
}
```

I want to test myMethod() in a JUnit test class :

```
public class MyClassTest {
    private static String[] myArray = {"A", "B", "C"};
    @Test
    public void myMethodTest() {
        Method method = Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass").getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", myArray.getClass());
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(null, myArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `invoke()` takes a vararg as argument, the Java compiler considers each element of the array that you pass as a vararg argument, i.e. it considers it equivalent to

```
method.invoke(null, "A", "B", "C");
```

You can just cast your array to an object to fix the issue:

```
method.invoke(null, (Object) myArray);
```

Comment: Works perfectly well ! That's the very first time I have to cast in Object ... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `String` in an object array:

```
Method method = Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass")
        .getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", myArray.getClass());
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(null, new Object[] {myArray});
```

The second parameter to `method.invoke()` requires an array or vararg of the method's arguments. For your method, you only have a single argument (which also happens to be an array), but you still need to wrap it in an array.

Comment: Excellent workaround for this vararg problem ! Thanks